# Doubly linked list not taking input after calling a delete function

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

Greetings stack overflow. My program is supposed to take a user inputted line of characters and append them to a list. The program is also supposed to delete the most recent character appended if a hashtag is read in the input.

My program *mostly works*, but I run into errors when I try to break it by adding too many hashtags. Upon doing this the list stops accepting appends will display nothing if one too many hashtags are used.

I hope I only included what I thought was useful code, sorry if the main function was not necessary.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class doubleList
{
    public:
        doubleList() { first = NULL; } // constructor

        void append(char); // adds entry to the end of the list
        void remove_last(); // removes the last item from a list

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const doubleList& l); // outputs in forward order

    private:
        struct Node
        {
            char data;
            Node *next;
            Node *prev;
        };
        Node *first;
        Node *last;  
};

void doubleList::append(char entry)
{
    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp -> data = entry;
    temp -> next = NULL;

    if (first == NULL)
    {
        first = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        last -> next = temp;
        temp -> prev = last;
        last = temp;
    }
}

void doubleList::remove_last()
{
    if (first -> next == NULL)
    {
        delete first;
    }
    else if (first != NULL)
    {
        last = last -> prev;
        delete last -> next;
        last -> next = NULL;
    }
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const doubleList& l)
{
    doubleList::Node* q;
    q = l.first;

    while (q != NULL)
    {
        out << q -> data;
        q = q -> next;
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    doubleList list;
    char ch[100];

    cout << "Enter a line of characters; # will delete the most recent character." << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            cin.get(ch[i]);
            list.append(ch[i]);

            if (ch[i] == '#')
            {
                list.remove_last();
                list.remove_last(); // called twice becaue it removes the hashtag from the list
            }                       // and i was too lazy to make it so it doesnt do that so this
                                    // is simply an easier fix
            if (ch[i] == '\n')      // exits the loop when enter is clicked
                break;
        }

    cout << list;

    return 0;
}
```

A successful run of my program would look like:

`Enter a line of characters; # will delete the most recent character.`

`abcd##fg`

`abfg`

My program when too many hashtags are added:

`Enter a line of characters; # will delete the most recent character.`

`ab#####efgh`

Nothing is shown after user input is taken. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a [mre].   What is append()?  You are also missing includes to for this to compile.

Comment: I've removed a lot of the code as previously stated, only showing the functions that I believe are the problem. The append function listed in the main function would add data to the end of the list. Sorry for forgetting about that one. Does this clear up anything?

Comment: Note: `first -> next` is more commonly (always?) written `first->next`.

Comment: With updated code and input of ` ab#####efgh` t crashes for me in `doubleList::append()` on `operator new(unsigned long)`.  This is an entirely different problem.

Comment: Its not crashing for me when I use your input, nothing is outputted though.

Comment: It could just be platform difference (why it didn't crash for you).  It looks like you are all set with the answer from @VladfromMoscow but I suggest you study the implementation of `remove_last()` that I shared with you as the early return style leads to less branched code.  It's a matter of opinion if that is better or worse.

Comment: __Tip for a [mre]:__ Don't rely on user input. You have example input that causes the crash, so simply assume that is the input. (Still, shorter input would be better. Based on the problem description, I would guess that an input of `a##d` is enough to reproduce the problem.) That is, your main function could be reduced to `int main() { doubleList list; list.append('a'); list.append('#'); list.remove_last(); list.remove_last(); list.append('#'); list.remove_last(); list.remove_last(); list.append('d'); cout << list; }`. Keep it simple, ignore your end functionality, and focus on the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also set the pointer `last` to `nullptr` in the constructor

```
doubleList() { first = nullptr; last = nullptr; }
```

The function `append` is incorrect because it does not set the data member `prev` of the first node appended to the list. It should be written like

```
void doubleList::append(char entry)
{
    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp -> data = entry;
    temp -> next = nullptr;
    temp -> prev = last; 

    if (first == NULL)
    {
        first = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        last -> next = temp;
    }

    last = temp;
}
```

The function `removeList` can invoke undefined behavior because in the very beginning of the function it does not check whether the pointer `first` is equal to `nullptr`. And after deleting the node pointed to by the pointer `first` it does not set the pointers `first` and `last` to `nullptr`. The function can be defined the following way.

```
void doubleList::remove_last()
{
    if ( last )
    {
        Node *tmp = last;

        last = last->prev;

        if ( last != nullptr )
        {
            last->next = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            first = nullptr;
        }

        delete temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it seems I was close, just not exactly there. I assume nullptr is more widely used than NULL so I'll start using that from now on.

Comment: @user486543 `nullptr` is a `nullptr_t`, which allows compiler type checking (better type safety) and disambiguation. Using it should result in fewer bugs, better diagnostics, and less template-wrangling. Even if it wasn't growing in use I'd recommend using it (and I'd be puzzling over why people weren't picking up on it faster).

Answer (score 0):

You rely on first being NULL when deallocated in `remove_last()` but do not set it after the `free`.  As your code is incomplete, I cannot tell what `last` is, and why you your logic doesn't rely on it in `remove_last()` instead of `first`.

Something along these lines (untested);

```
void doubleList::remove_last() {
    if(!last) return;

    if(last == first) {
       free last;
       first = nullptr;
       last = nullptr;
       return;
    }
  
    last = last->prev;
    free last->next;
    last->next = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Would you like to see the entirety of my code? its just under a hundred lines, but I didn't want to paste it all as I feel like I would be shamed if I were to showcase my entire code.

Comment: No, I want you to post _minimal_ working code.

Comment: Does the code look more sufficient now?

Comment: You have yet to add header includes so it doesn't compile yet, using namespace.  I.e. try to compile your stuff before you ask us to.